# How to add k-state-error class to kendo date picker

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to add k-state-error class in onChange event of Kendo date picker.

```
 function onChange(e) {
    if (e.date == undefined) {
        $(this).closest('span').addClass("myclass");
        $(this).parent('span').addClass("myclass");
        $(this).child('span').addClass("myclass");
    }
}
```

how can i access that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `change` event handler `$(this)` refers to `DatePicker` and not the original `input`. So you should use `$(this.element)` instead.

```
$("#date").kendoDatePicker({
    change: onChange
    }
});

function onChange(e) {
    if (!e.sender.value()) {
        $(this.element).closest('span').addClass("myclass");
        $(this.element).parent('span').addClass("myclass");
        // NOTE: The following will actually not work since it does not have child 
        // $(this.element).child('span').addClass("myclass");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: And define the style as:

```
.myclass {
    border: 3px solid red !important;
}
```

Running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Csp6P/

Comment: This one is  not Adding Red border to my date picker?